# String having r & g separated by 5 characters! (Error:String index out of range error)

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

Given an input string,check whether the string has char 'r' & 'g' separated be exactly 5 characters.
For the following code, the error is String index out of range error.
Can't figure out whats wrong

My code for class having function that checks for pattern:

```
public class classb {
String s = new String();

   public int match(String str){
        int counter = 0;
        int j;
        s=str;
        for(j=0;j<(s.length()-6);j++){
            if(s.charAt(j)=='r' && s.charAt(j+6)=='g') {
                counter=1;
                break;
            }
            if(s.charAt(j)=='g' && s.charAt(j+6)=='r'){
                counter=1;
                break;
            }

            while(s.charAt(j)!='r' || s.charAt(j)!='g'){
                if(j<(s.length()-6))
                    j++;
                else
                    break;
            }

        }

        return counter;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class classa 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String a = new String();
    int count;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    a= sc.nextLine();
    classb x = new classb();
    count=x.match(a);
    if(count==1)
        System.out.println("Pattern found ");
    else if(count==0)
        System.out.println("Pattern not found ");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this problem, `r.{5}g`.

The `r` says that the pattern starts with `r`, and the `g` says that it ends with `g`. The `.` means any character, and the `{5}` means that there are exactly 5 (in this case of any character).

And to implement this, you would just use the method `String#matches("r.{5}g")`.

Comment: I sure can.But the question also said you cannot use direct functions to solve.

Comment: @AishwaryaR Ah, I see. In that case you can split the `String` with the regex `(?=r)`, so that the `r` stays in each of the `String`s in the array, and iterate through it, checking if the 7th character is a `g`.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem in your code is this:

```
        for(j=0;j<s.length();j++){
        while(s.charAt(j)!='r' || s.charAt(j)!='g')
            j++;
```

You have a loop for j where you increase J - but inside that loop you increase j again. Below that, you use j+6 in an index and you haven't checked to see if j+6 is too long. So you're repeatedly modifying j and checking 6 characters out without ever checking to see if those are in bounds.

I'd start by stopping your for loop at s.length()-6. If an r or g sequence starts in those last spots it can't complete, so no need to check them - and then your j+6 logic will work and not blow up.

Comment: Yeah,absolutely true.Done with those edits...but still for the above code it doesn't recognize the pattern even if it's present.The counter statement is not reached.